# SpringBoot dependency outside jar in maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

My SpringBoot project has a outside jar, the jar need to get some configFile, the configfiles are in `src/main/resources/config`,after `mvn package` ,the `config` is in `BOOT-INF\classes\config`,but the outside jar got the config path is: `/BOOT-INF/lib/config-xxx-1.0.8.jar!/config`, how the jar get the right path?   when i debug in idea,it can get the right path.
jar 's code:

```java
 public static String getConfigPathUtil() {
        String configPath = ConfigPathUtil.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        try {
            configPath = URLDecoder.decode(configPath, "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var2) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Transcoding mistakes when the configuration file path" + var2.getMessage());
        }
        File f = new File(configPath);
        configPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        if (configPath.endsWith(".jar")) {
            configPath = configPath.substring(0, configPath.lastIndexOf(LIB_PATH));
        }
        if (configPath.endsWith(BIN_PATH_ENDSWITH)) {
            configPath = configPath.substring(0, configPath.lastIndexOf(BIN_PATH_ENDSWITH));
        }
        configPath = configPath.replace(BIN_PATH, File.separator);
        configPath = configPath + CONFIG_PATH;
        return configPath;
    }
```

maven pom:

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>config-xxx</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/config-xxx-1.0.8.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

springboo-maven-plugin

```xml
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <mainClass>com.xxx.ManagementApplication</mainClass>
               <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you not able to locate the configs inside the jar? The question is not quite clear..

Comment: the configs is in jar: BOOT-INF\classes\config ,  but the outside dependency jar config-xxx-1.0.8.jar can't find the config

Comment: So your application is acting as an aggregator, which glues the config to launch the dependency jar application/functionality?

Comment: now I resolve it,I decompile the jar,change the code,then use mvn to package. thanks for your reply.